How do I get rid of the artifacts on this sphere?
I'm currently learning Blender because I need it for a university project. I have some previous C4D experience, but never really learned topology and modelling.
I have the following problem: The grooves in the sphere cause artifacts. At first I tried to remove them with the knife tool, but I didn't know how to set the cuts:  
    
But if I dissolve the edges, other artifacts simply form. The surface has to be smooth, and will be a little bit reflective. Like chrome but with a higher roughness.:     
Another problem are the artifacts at the edge of the countersink. I already added supportive cuts, but can't get rid of them. Many thanks in advance for your help!  
 

Hello and welcome to BSE. The vertical cuts are interfering with the edge flow of the edge loop of the top sphere. You have to move the topology 1 level lower as demonstrated by moonboots answer.

Try this topology:

I began by creating this vertex:

Then bevel this edge:

Extrude:

Add these edges and so on:

Result:

Topology for a square shape:

